# How do I create a tag and trigger to track when a button is clicked within a CSS Class?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm working on a site for a customer.  The site has a button on the top right corner that fires a modal window.

The client would like to track how many times the button is clicked.

I'm trying to create a trigger and tag to do this.  Unfortunately, I'm not having any luck.

The button has a class of RebateModalLink.  I'm trying to build my tag off of it.

Here is my trigger settings:

Name: RebateModalLink
Choose Event: Click
Configure Trigger: Targets All Elements
Fire On: Click Classes equals RebateModalLink

Here is my tag:

Name: Rebate Button Click
Choose Product: Google Analytics
Choose a Tag Type: Universal Analytics

Configure Tag
  - Tag Type: Universal Analytics
  - Tracking ID: The ID of GA
  - Track Type: Event
  - Category: Click Classes
  - Action: Click Classes
  - Label: click
  - Value: true

Fire on: RebateModalLink

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you specify how you aren't successful? Do you not see clicks in GA, or Real-Time, or??? In GTM preview mode, as soon as you click that modal button, can you check the dataLayer to see the last object pushed to it? It should be a 'gtm.click' event, but what is the 'gtm.element' value? Basically, I'd like to see if the element that's clicked actually does have the specified class.

Comment: When I'm in GA I'm not seeing the event in the event section.

Comment: Data in GA doesn't get processed (and show up in your reports) until about 24 hours after the initial action. You could install GA Debugger to see if your hit actually goes through. Also, less reliably, check in Real-time reports for your event.

Comment: I should have clarified this.  I am using the Real-time reports.

Comment: What were the results of using GA Debugger to check? Check to see also if you have some filters set up that may block your hits.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I'm still learning GTM and I didn't know about the debugger.  I got the trigger working correctly!  I'll double check the event section to see if it is being recorded.

Comment: No problem, keep us updated on what you find out. It sounds like you have done everything correctly in terms of the tag setup, may just need to adjust trigger.

Comment: I also tweaked the trigger.  Here are the settings that I'm using on the tag and trigger:

Comment: Sorry, don't see the updates.

Comment: I just posted my answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are my trigger settings:

Name: RebateModalLink 
Choose Event: Click Configure 
Trigger: Targets All Elements 
Fire On: Click URL cotains getrebate.png

Here are my tag settings:

Name: Rebate Button 
Click Choose Product: 
Google Analytics Choose a Tag Type: Universal Analytics

Configure Tag

Tag Type: Universal Analytics 
Tracking ID: The ID of GA 
Track Type: Event 
Category: "Rebate" Button"
Action: "Clicked" 
Non-Interaction Hit: False

Fire on: RebateModalLink

The biggest mistake I was making was I was checking for a class on the href and not the image.  When I changed it to check the filename of the image, I got the trigger to work.  I slightly modified the Tag to report info correctly.